# Are the maximal cyclotomic field contained in a number field and its Hilbert class group the same?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. If $d$  be the smallest even integer such that $\Bbb Q (\zeta_d) \subset K,$  then I wanted to prove that if $d'>d$ then $\Bbb Q (\zeta_{d'}) \not\subset H(K),$ where $H(K)$ is Hilbert class field $K.$

I understand that it is not true in general. Can I see this working with some assumptions?

Ps. thanks to the comment of  Franz Lemmermeyer.

Comment: ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-5})$.

Comment: I assume that $d$ should be the largest even integer $\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

The key word is genus theory. The genus class field of a number field $K$ is the
maximal unramified extension $KF/K$ where $F/{\mathbb Q}$ is abelian. Thus number fields with trivial genus class field have the desired property.

Genus theory is quite explicit for cyclic extensions $K/{\mathbb Q}$, so in this case you will get conditions that can be verified easily. For general number fields $K$, not a whole lot is known.